# Can you dump a running Lua coroutine to a file for a later resume?

Tags: serialization, lua, coroutine

While thinking of load/save mechanics for a game using Lua coroutines a quite interesting question has arisen -- can you dump a running Lua state to file completely? Apart from the obvious solutions of dumping the environment two notable problems have arisen -- dumping functions (which I think is easier), and dumping coroutines.

The latter made me wonder, whether it is possible at all to dump a running coroutine for a later resume call. The uses for that would be quite wide -- in the long run it would allow serialization of running tasks and passing them around Erlang style.

Hence the question -- is it possible?

I'm not searching for the (maybe obvious) "no" answer, for it probably is possible at some degree of work required (ergo in the worst case one could try to hack the compiler). I'm interested in how hard it would be...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [PlutoLibrary](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PlutoLibrary) provides "heavy duty persistence" for Lua. It can serialize and deserialize coroutines.

Comment: Note that Pluto is not compatible with LuaJIT2 (as well as all other solutions I know, though).

Comment: I just noticed this: http://code.google.com/p/corsix-th/wiki/Persistance  Should work with LuaJIT, but it requires all functions be annotated with permanent names. On the plus side, it allows code reloading.

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental module [lper](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lper) that can save and restore the state of the entire Lua interpreter. I've personally never played with it, as it depends on the [Linux persistent memory](http://freshmeat.net/projects/lpsm/) library that has no obvious Windows counterpart. It probably would serve as a starting point for further research.

There is also a list of Lua persistence solutions in the [wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization).

Comment: Unfortunately the former is really dependent on Linux, and the latter only provides tips for table serialization :/

Comment: @Kornel, sure. But the wiki page, although probably not correctly tiltled, does list Pluto. Besides, since anything can be stored in a table, including coroutines and closures, a complete solution to table persistence has to include persistence for those more "interesting" values as well.